# Filter rows where values in one column are shared by different categories in another, using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, duplicates

I have a data frame:

```
col1    col2    col3

a        1      n1
a        1      n2
a        2      n3  
a        2      n4
b        2      n5
b        3      n6
c        4      n7
c        5      n8
c        6      n9
```

And I want to return all rows in which the value in col2 is shared by two or more categories in col1, i.e:

```
a   2   n3
a   2   n4
b   2   n5
```

This seems like such a simple problem, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to find a solution that works. Been playing about with combinations of filter, duplicate in dplyr etc. to no avail. Much of the trouble comes from there being multiple duplicates in col2 I don't want to filter out (as they're the same in col1).

```
data %>% group_by(col1) %>% filter(???)
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: I think I get something quite close with: 

`data %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% filter(n() == 1 | col1 == 2)`

It doesn't give me a list of all duplicates - the matching originals - but at least one of every matching pair. Hmmm...

Comment: I think you mean "all rows in which the value in col2 is shared by **two** or more categories in col1" ? Every value has one or more categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? Group on `col2` and look for cases with > 1 value for `col1`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(col2) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(col1) > 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  col1   col2 col3 
  <chr> <int> <chr>
1 a         2 n3   
2 a         2 n4   
3 b         2 n5
```

Comment: Of course it does! I'm a bit of a numpty. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
subset(data, col2 %in% names(which(lengths(with(unique(data[1:2]), 
    split(col1, col2))) > 1)))
  col1 col2 col3
3    a    2   n3
4    a    2   n4
5    b    2   n5
```